# How to apply different functions to different rows of same column in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

## Background

I am trying to predict the speed of a vehicle following another vehicle using the equations below:

[image]

Please note that the Un(t) in the denominator of second equation is a typo. It is actually delta t.

where,

Un(t) = speed of following vehicle at time t,
CC8 = 1.765, CC9 = 1.04,
delta t = time step = 1 second,
sn(t) = front bumper to front bumper distance between the two vehicles,
CC0 = 4.4, L_n-1 = Length of lead vehicle,

Please ignore the uf and note that 3.6 is just used to ensure that the units of speed are km/hr. Also, since the vehicle positions change over time due to speed, it is important to estimate those as well.

## Calculations in Excel

I can successfully apply these equations in Excel as follows:

[image]

Note that:
Local.Y = Observed longitudinal position of following vehicle from a fixed reference point (m),
pred_Local.Y = Predicted longitudinal position of following vehicle,
PrecVehLocalY = Observed longitudinal position of lead vehicle,
Un = Observed speed of following vehicle (m/s),
Un_dt_1 = predicted speed of following vehicle using the first equation in the 1st image,
Un_dt_2 = predicted speed of following vehicle using the 2nd equation,
Un_dt = minimum of Un_dt_1 and Un_dt_2
Ln = actual length of lead vehicle = L_n-1 in the equation,
sn_minus_Ln = observed distance between front bumper of following vehicle and rear bumper of lead vehicle; sn is the front-to front distance,
pred_sn_minus_Ln = predicted front-to-rear distance;

You can see that the first row of predicted variables use the observed variables from one time step before. But after that the consecutive rows use the predicted variables only. I have no idea how can I do the same in R? Please help. I want to use `dplyr`.

#### Example data for R

```
structure(list(Local.Y = c(50.71994, 60.37412, 69.99005, 78.60745
), Un = c(9.48762, 9.93521, 8.9674, 8.33772), PrecVehLocalY = c(70.19624, 
78.50749, 86.49717, 93.4731), Ln = c(3.9019, 3.9019, 3.9019, 
3.9019), sn_minus_Ln = c(15.5744, 14.23147, 12.60522, 10.96375
)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Local.Y", 
"Un", "PrecVehLocalY", "Ln", "sn_minus_Ln"))
```

### What I have tried

Please don't close this question. I have tried using following code but it only works for the first row:

```
df %>% 
mutate(Un_dt_1 = lag(Un)*3.6 + 3.6*(1.765+(1.765-1.04)*lag(Un)*3.6/80))
```

'ifelse' could be an option but I am not sure what conditions should I provide for `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

#### Desired Output

```
structure(list(Local.Y = c(50.71994, 60.37412, 69.99005, 78.60745
), Un = c(9.48762, 9.93521, 8.9674, 8.33772), PrecVehLocalY = c(70.19624, 
78.50749, 86.49717, 93.4731), Ln = c(3.9019, 3.9019, 3.9019, 
3.9019), sn_minus_Ln = c(15.5744, 14.23147, 12.60522, 10.96375
), pred_Local.Y = c(NA, 57.624865, 69.5024275, 80.13921125), 
    pred_sn_minus_Ln = c(NA, 16.980725, 13.0928425, 9.43198875
    ), Un_dt_1 = c(NA, 41.62375297, 47.89427328, 53.12221615), 
    Un_dt_2 = c(NA, 40.22784, 45.29061, 31.294233), Un_dt = c(NA, 
    40.22784, 45.29061, 31.294233)), .Names = c("Local.Y", "Un", 
"PrecVehLocalY", "Ln", "sn_minus_Ln", "pred_Local.Y", "pred_sn_minus_Ln", 
"Un_dt_1", "Un_dt_2", "Un_dt"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It seems like you are asking for someone to translate your code into R?

Comment: @nrussell, I just need a starting point. Not asking for full code.

Comment: Why do you want to use `dplyr` specifically? What if there is a better approach?

Comment: @nruscell,  I have multiple vehicle pairs. The example data here only contains few rows of 1 vehicle pair. Using `dplyr` I can do `group_by(Vehicle.ID2) %>% mutate(Un_dt_1 = ...)`. But if `dplyr` is not suitable I can use other approaches.

Comment: You can do similar things to `group_by` without `dplyr`. I personally use `data.table` quite a bit, where your comment example would translate as something like `dt[ , Un_dt_1 := ... , by = Vehicle.ID2 ]`, where the ellipsis would be replaced by `function(variable_column)`. My understanding is that this would give you the same result.

Comment: Please take the following as constructive criticism:
I think the reason you're getting down-votes is because it comes across as asking someone else to do your work. Consider reducing your question to a single problem; maybe one column for which you're struggling to find a solution. Your question is basically a series of problems with the same or similar solutions, so ask people how to solve that problem and learn from that, rather than asking them to write your code for you. 
People want to teach you to fish. They don't want to go fishing for you, cook what they catch, and serve it to you.

Comment: @rosscova, Thanks for your comment. I understand your point. I am not asking for code. I have presented the problem and the solution in Excel. Then I showed what I tried in R to achieve the same but that didn't work. I would've used only 1 column if the columns did not depend on each other. Maybe I should create hypothetical data, with same problems but only in 1 column and post the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

( Adding a separate answer because I'm starting from scratch )

I'm glad I understand your question better now, it is certainly more complex a solution than I first thought.

Here's a completely different way to go about it, given that your calculations need to happen in sequence. Because there's such a sequence involved (ie: it's important for every calculation that the ones before it have been completed first), I think the best way is with a `for` loop. This also allows for specifying different calculations for `Un_dt_1`, `Un_dt_2`, and `pred_Local.Y` on the first run compared with subsequent runs:

```
for( i in ( seq_len( nrow(df)-1 ) + 1 ) ) {
    if( i <= 2L ) {
        df$Un_dt_1[i] <- df$Un[i-1] * 3.6 + 
            3.6 * ( 1.765 + ( 1.765 - 1.04 ) * 
                        df$Un[1] * 3.6 / 80 ) * 1
        df$Un_dt_2[i] <- 3.6 * ( df$sn_minus_Ln[i-1] - 4.4 ) / 1
    } else {
        df$Un_dt_1[i] <- df$Un_dt[i-1] + 
            3.6 * ( 1.765 + ( 1.765 - 1.04 ) * 
                        df$Un_dt[i-1] / 80 ) * 1
        df$Un_dt_2[i] <- 3.6 * ( df$pred_sn_minus_Ln[i-1] - 4.4 ) / 1
    }
    df$Un_dt[i] <- pmin( df$Un_dt_1[i], df$Un_dt_2[i] )
    if( i <= 2 ) {
        df$pred_Local.Y[i] <- df$Local.Y[i-1] + 
            0.5 * ( ( df$Un_dt[i] + df$Un[i-1] ) / 3.6 ) * 1
    } else {
        df$pred_Local.Y[i] <- df$pred_Local.Y[i-1] + 
            0.5 * ( ( df$Un_dt[i] + df$Un_dt[i-1] ) / 3.6 ) * 1
    }

    df$pred_sn_minus_Ln[i] <- df$PrecVehLocalY[i] - df$pred_Local.Y[i] - df$Ln[i]
}
```

Notice the `seq_len` call to begin the loop will return all values from 2, ascending to the end of your frame. Then row 2 is treated as a special case, where `Un_dt_1`, `Un_dt_2`, and `pred_Local.Y` are calculated in a different way to subsequent rows.

If you turn this into a `function`, you can then run it on all groups in your larger dataset. Alternatively, you could nest this in another `for` loop, subsetting the group as the first step in that larger loop.

While I (and I believe most others) think it's best to stay away from `for` loops when possible, they're not altogether evil. They do have their place, and I believe your problem here is one case where a for loop is a reasonable solution.

EDIT: OK, it seems to give the right output now. I hadn't noticed a few differences between rows. Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help. `for loop` works without problems. It is slow but I guess this is the only workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little that I hope will get you started, using the `data.table` package (my personal choice, certainly not the only way):

```
library( data.table )
setDT( df )
df[ , Un_dt_1 := shift( Un, n = 1L, type = "lag" ) * 3.6 + 
          3.6 * ( 1.765 + ( 1.765 - 1.04 ) * 
                      shift( Un, n = 1L, type = "lag" ) * 
                      3.6 / 80 ) 
   ]

df[ , Un_dt_2 := 
          3.6 * ( shift( sn_minus_Ln, n = 1L, type = "lag" ) - 4.4 ) / 1 
   ]
```

Note the use of the `shift` function, to offset a reference by a certain number of rows `n` (default is 1), in the direction specified by `type` ("lag" looks up, "lead" looks down). The values input here are actually the defaults, so you can leave them out, but I like to include them for completeness.

I think the method used here will work for all of the columns you've shown in your spreadsheet. If you need to apply things by a grouping variable, you'll need something like the following:

```
df[ , output_column := function(x), by = group ]
```

Where `function` is the function you'd like to apply, `x` is the input column (or columns) to the function, and `group` is a column with a unique group identifier.

EDIT in response to OP's comment:
There's no reason you can't add more variables to the calculation, or reference variables already calculated into a new calculation. For example, `Un_dt` relies on the two columns for which I've included calculations above, so reference each of them in your next step:

```
df[ , Un_dt := pmin( Un_dt_1, Un_dt_2 ) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the use of `lag` and `lead` here. It is similar to what I've shown in my code. This only works for calculating the very first value of `Un_dt_1` and `Un_dt_2`. Please note that all subsequent values can't be calculated using `Un` and `sn_minus_Ln` respectively. Rather, they depend on `Un_dt` and `pred_sn_minus_Ln`. So for the same column, the first value depends on 1 variable and all subsequent values depend on a different variable. That's why I showed my calculations in Excel. I don't know how to tell R to use different variables for different rows.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. Finding the `min` of two variables is straightforward as you showed. But what about `Un_dt_1`? In your code (as well as mine, as shown in question) `Un_dt_1` depends on `Un` in previous row. This gives the correct calculation for first value of `Un_dt_1`. Now, see the second value of `Un_dt_1` in the attached Excel figure. It does not depend on `Un` at all. Instead, it depends on `Un_dt`. In other words, the same column uses one variable for first calculation and a different variable for all other subsequent calculations, while the formula remained the same.

Comment: Ah yes, I see! I hadn't noticed that, sorry. That does make it more complicated. I'll add an example when I have a chance.